# Tech needed to make combustion light gas gun more feasible on specialized tanks/assault guns

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, chemistry, materials, guns

I have an opponent in my setting that can only be defeated by either sustained tank gun rounds using a lot of high velocity rounds (APFSDS) or a few very high velocity rounds. Initially I planned on going with railguns, however the power source for those proved to be challenging to work around.

Instead, I have chosen to go with a combustion light gas gun (CLG) on what is essentially a classic casemate assault gun. Basically, reintroducing the tank destroyer SPG. Such a vehicle is specialized to be able to use a CLG gun and house the required facilities to fire such a weapon reliably. Its operation is more akin to how the US used M18 tank destroyers during WW2. Basically, called upon as needed, they aren't going to be patrolling or brawling up close and personnel. Whatever combat they'll be engaged in, will be based on the fact that they were called in to help. More than average maintenance for the tank is okay compared to the average main battle tank.

Some reading posed a few hard negatives for the CLG gun in terms of storage and safety though. The risk of detonation is apparently problematic at present.

**What technological/material science innovations are necessary to be able to mount a CLG gun on a tank such that it can be used in combat situations reliably?**

While CLG guns are useful for artillery, in this case I'm looking for raw penetration power in a direct line of sight engagement at long ranges. One can assume the round being fired is capable of surviving such forces and temperatures associated with CLG or railguns.

Comment: The innovation needed is a way to consistently ignite the propellant.

Comment: What are your expectations for this answer in terms of detail? Anyone who could give you a rational answer down to, "use X material to protect the gas containment system" or some such would be running to the patent office, not posting it here. See: [Advice concerning questions asking HOW to implement a technological procedure or device](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609).

Comment: @JBH I think the concern is that he does not know what it is about LGGs that keep them from seeing military use today.  Knowing what problem needs to be solved is not the same as asking for an exact solution to the problem.

Comment: It looks like you are tying yourself in knots with all these technical questions. It is not clear what level of detail you will consider authoritative in an answer. Do you have a goal in mind in designing your hovertank world? What would stop you just inserting FUTURE MISSILE TECNOLOGY X into the world to solve your problems>

Comment: @Daron Really all I'm looking for is a sort of "good enough" reason to make sense for the armament of this universe. But also, some design considerations to be weary of. With railguns and coilguns power sources and switches are the go-to problem to solve. A similar thing with lasers since they're discussed a lot. I'm just exploring the issues with other weapons that don't get many mentions or are less known. The ancillary problems to these weapons can be waved off generally but waving away specifics makes for a better understanding of a platform, rather than waving the entire system itself.

Answer (score 2):

Frame Challenge: Use more powerful weapons

Your basic premise is that you need high velocity rounds. However, since you haven't said otherwise, I will assume that you need high velocity for the high resulting kinetic energy. As such, what you really need is a more powerful weapon. Tanks have multiple options for this. There are HEAT rounds (high explosive anti tank rounds). There are tactical nukes shells, which could be put on howitzer (courtesy of nosajimiki) There are depleted uranium and tungsten carbide tank penetrators, which have an insane level of damage potential. And if any of these options are not powerful enough, you could always have multiple tanks (or even just 1 tank) apply all of these options onto your super durable target.

### TL;DR

In short, other modern military weaponry will deliver the same destructive potential, kinetic energy, and force as you need. In fact, due to the fact that some explosives send material flying many times the speed of sound, I would suggest HEAT rounds.

Comment: Nuclear "tank" shells are not exactly science fiction.  The W-48 is a 155mm nuclear shell designed to be fired from an M109 Self propelled howitzer (which is basically just a tank built to fulfill the role of artillery).  So, the US has had this capability since 1963.

Comment: @Nosajimiki even better, it's more realistic. I just wasn't sure if it existed yet. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: for the scenario you're describing, a [conventional light gas gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-gas_gun) appears to be a better choice.

You want to achieve extremely high projectile velocities. The point of using a light gas gun is that it can do that. It needs to keep the molecular weight of the gas that expands to accelerate the projectile as low as possible. That makes straight hydrogen the best choice at that end.

A combustion light gas gun is going to be burning hydrogen in oxygen and expanding extremely hot H2O. That has a molecular weight of 18, as opposed to 2 for straight hydrogen. That's a big disadvantage. You really don't want to be burning hydrogen in fluorine: the resulting HF has a molecular weight of 20 and is horribly dangerous and corrosive.

The conventional light gas gun is [driven by a piston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-gas_gun#Design_physics), which is usually propelled by conventional gun propellant, which is well understood, and relatively safe and flexible in use (by explosives standards). By choosing the diameter of the piston, and its size relative to the final gun barrel, you have a lot of control over performance. Its drawback is that it's larger and heavier than the combustion light gas gun.

Given that you're deploying these guns on specialised vehicles, to be called out for the engagements that require them, the size and weight drawbacks of the conventional light gas gun seem like a tolerable downside given its performance advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [electrothermal accelerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma-powered_cannon) (Or Plasma Cannon): Operates on a basic level just as a conventional gun, And somewhat like a Light Gas Gun. Replacing the chemical explosion with a high voltage electric arc generated plasma; Thus sometimes referred to as a Thunder Canon. Since the gun does not require any volatile materials for the projectile, it is safer to operate than conventional artillery. The charge delivered in the shot determines the velocity of the projectile, so it can be dialed in to the needs of the situation. No propellant is needed ie: gunpowder so more ammunition can be stored, and safely.

Though not capable of accelerating a projectile to the theoretical upper end of a rail gun, The plasma cannon is comparable in function and performance. With a great deal less demand for electricity and superconducting electromagnets.

The plasma cannon does come with its own needs. Mechanically it is more complex with more moving parts than a rail gun. Perhaps requiring a 2 stage ignition to reach required performance.

> To generate the energy required to make a plasma discharge, a high
> current, high voltage source, and a large capacitor bank are used.
> Both are attached in series to the electrode system in the cannon's
> barrel. The capacitor is loaded with as high a voltage as possible.
> However, militarily useful energy is achieved with as little as
> several kilojoules. The capacitor is then discharged. The gap between
> the electrodes ionizes, turning the non-flammable propellant medium
> into a super heated conductive plasma. Associated volumetric expansion
> propels the projectile from the barrel at high velocity.

Comment: "Though not capable of accelerating a projectile to the theoretical upper end of a rail gun" <- I don't see why this would be true.  As you heat a gas, the speed at which it can expand also increases. While I can't say if it would be as weight or energy efficient as an equivalent rail gun, the max speed of a plasma cannon could be very high.

Comment: A rail gun will accelerate the projectile for the full length of the rail/barrel Where a projectile fired in this manner does too the proportional amount of the acceleration decreases with the length of the barrel. I suppose it would be "of equivalent size"  comparison.

Answer (score 1):

### Accuracy and Reloadability

An LGG is not that hard to make, but they have 2 big issues when it comes to military applications. They are hard to reload, and they are hard to make accurate.

When it comes to reloading, you have a powder chamber to refill, the piston to reset, refilling the pump tube with a pressurized light gas, and the diaphragm and slug to replace. Reloading such a weapon without a self contained ordinance can be quite time consuming.  The best solution is to make one large replaceable inner-tube preloaded with all of these things.  Your ammo would be closer to the size, cost, and complexity of a missile than a bullet by the time you are done, but this is actually not a deal beaker for a specialty weapon like the one in your story; so, making a reloadable LGG is not a big deal for what you are proposing.

The second, and bigger problem is with the accuracy. The gun fires only when the diaphragm ruptures; however, designing a diaphragm to rupture at just the right place under just the right pressure is MUCH harder than it sounds.  If the rupture happens even slightly off center or slightly asymmetrically it can add a spin to the bullet that can send it off course.  Then there is making it rupture at the exact right pressure since the tiniest of manufacturing defects can cause it to rupture at too high or low of a pressure changing the expected speed and arc of the bullet considerably.  So, while an LGG can in theory go much farther than conventional artillery, we don't use them because conventional artillery is much more accurate giving it a better effective range.

To solve the accuracy issue, you need one of the following:

**1: Better Manufacturing:**  If you could mill the diaphragm down to molecular levels of precision and refine the materials used to be 100% devoid of defects, then you should be able to control the diaphragm's rupture to the exact specifications you need to fire the gun accurately and consistently.  But this degree of manufacturing accuracy could have all sorts of un-intended side-effects on other technologies in your setting. It's been theorized that truly defect free manufacturing could be used to make alloys and composites 5-10 times tougher than anything we can make to date which could change everything about the tech level of your civilization.

**2: Self Guided Ordinance:**  Conventional artillery already uses self guided ordinance these days so that a slug can correct its course mid fight to make up for inconsistency in the firing process.  The issue is that designing components that can survive the massive accelerations caused in a conventional artillery piece are already extraordinary.  You'd have to develop even tougher components to withstand the even higher acceleration rates seen in an LGG.  This is probably your best option though because you could explain tougher specialized self-guidance systems without expecting a flood of other possibilities being opened up that don't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Igniting the Gas Uniformly**

> While this technology does appear to provide higher velocities, the main drawback with gaseous or liquid propellants for gun systems is the difficulty in getting uniform and predictable ignition and muzzle velocities.

My understanding is you have a sealed chamber of gas behind the bullet. Ideally you want to ignite the gas simultaneously at all points and it just pops the bullet out. In reality you have to light it somewhere. For example if you light from behind then as the ignition moves forwards through the chamber it will create pressure waves that bounce back and forth inside the chamber and make for non-uniform bullet popping. This does not happen in solid fuel because the spark moves much faster than the fuel itself.

The extract is from Wikipedia. The only citation is [this report from UTRON](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA462130.pdf) They discuss pressure waves and igniting the propellant on pages 15,16 of the report. So I presume the extract is taken from a broad reading of the report. UTRON claims to have solved the ignition issues at least for big big guns.